# using created virtualenv in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I created a project and it's virtualenv system using python and it was intended to use python3. The command to create is was

```
virtualenv envname --python=python3
```

but now that I've upgraded my pc and reinstalled ubuntu and reinstalled everything the virtualenv isn't using python3 but python2, I checked using `python --version` .

The thing is I can't just switch to using `python3 manage.py runserver` for django and resolve the issue because it considers `pip3` has no installed packages.

Wondering if there's a command to fix this bug.

Comment: I guess that python3 has been uninstalled since you said that you have reinstalled Ubuntu, In that case, I'm afraid you will have to install python3 again.

Comment: it's installed, I can confirm using `python3 --version`

Comment: To install the virtual environement, you could use `python3 -m venv envname`, then you're sure it's a python3 venv. If you need to install `pip3`, check this https://askubuntu.com/a/778058/321299

Answer (score 0):

Check if you still have the link in your virtualenv

```
./envname/bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 phxdev users     7 Jan 17 15:48 python -> python3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 phxdev users 10456 Jan 17 15:48 python3
```

If it is missing, just create it

Answer (score 0):

You reinstalled everything but you did not recreate virtual environvment.

So obvious answer is: recreate virtual environment.

My recomendation: use `pipenv`:

```
pip install pipenv 
mkdir django_project && cd django_project
pipenv install django
pipenv shell
```

Commit created `Pipfile` into VCS, don't loose your env-definition in future.